# ExtJS unable to get response headers

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, extjs

I am setting an `authenticated` header on the server side. Looking at Developer Tools - Network, I can see that the response is being set for that request:

```
authenticated:false
Content-Length:0
Server:Jetty(8.1.9.v20130131)
```

**However**, in my code I do not see this header.

```
Ext.Ajax.on('requestcomplete', function(conn, response, options) {
    Ext.Ajax.activeRequests--;

    if(response.getResponseHeader("authenticated") && response.getResponseHeader("authenticated") === "false") {
        alert('success');
    }

    ...
```

But it always comes back as undefined!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was occurring because I was sending a redirect on the server side.